# Bezier Curves OpenGL Move 3d Space According to 2d space

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, 2d, bezier

I am trying to think about the **following problem logically:**

Move an object in the 3d space in a fashion that represents a 2d user-generated bezier curve.

As of right now, the user can create his own bezier curve (Which can be seen on the right - I render it via a shader and have access to the x,y of each control point) . As of right now it has 4 control points that are moveable.

[image]

I can't seem to think of a way to convert this 2d curve into 3d space movement.
Trying to achieve the following:

[image]

From a lot of googling, I did find some resources but they all had info about how to convert the 2d point into 3d space and that is not what I want.

Thanks to whoever tries to help, currently lost. I don't need code but more of actual help in approaching such a problem.

Great day.

Comment: You are trying to project points on a 2D plane into a three-dimensional world. Do you have an idea which 3D plane you want to project it on? The z=0 plane for example would do exactly what you want unless you did something weird with your camera setup.

Comment: @Botje Highly appreciated, thanks for the fast response. How would one apply this logic into the z=0 plane? Care to share some math? ;P , I don't have any specific plane so I guess I can choose the z=0.

Comment: I think that maybe the most correct plane should be the one which has normal along the view direction and center on the center of the object. With this assumption your object will move exactly as the curve you drawn in the second picture. To do that just calculate the path on the XY plane (Z=0) then trasnform it with the transformation to the the final plane

Comment: @MarcoBeninca I am kinda lost with the math here, Logically I would want to create that plane (Either the one you said or z=0) , now whenever I have it, how would one move according to the curve? I seem to be lacking something. When you say "calculate the path", what do you mean?

Comment: The points in the Z=0 plane are 3D points with Z=0 (third dimension) then a transformation (4x4 matrix) of those points to the final plane will generate points in a 3D enviroment laying on the desired plane

Comment: @RRIL97 of course the next step is to calculate the correct 4x4 transformation

Answer (score 1):

In a two-dimensional plane, a point is defined by one or more combinations of its two basis vectors. (More combinations are possible if the two basis vectors are not orthogonal)

To project a point onto a three-dimensional plane, you need to embed the two-dimensional vectors **b1** and **b2** into three-dimensional space and apply a translation **t** (if needed).
In general, this matrix looks like:

```
[ b1x b2x tx ]
[ b1y b2y ty ]
[ b1z b2z tz ]
```

and you multiply (x,y,**1**) by the matrix above. If you multiply by (x,y,0) the translation is ignored which is not what you want in general.

Luckily, if you stick to an axis-aligned plane this is a lot simpler.
If we pick the z=0 plane, then the basis vectors are (1,0,0) and (0,1,0) and the translation is (0,0,0).
The matrix then becomes

```
[ 1 0 0 ]
[ 0 1 0 ]
[ 0 0 0 ]
```

and (x,y,1) times that matrix is just (x,y,0).
In other words, you can simply do:

```
vec2 bezier_2d = bezier(t);
vec3 bezier_3d = vec3(bezier_2d.x, bezier_2d.y, 0);
vec3 box_pos = original_pos + bezier_3d * scale;
```

where `bezier(t)` computes the value of the bezier function for a given timestep.

Comment: Hey, thanks.  Don't I need to "normalize" those bezier_3d points somehow? Since the screen for e.x goes from 0-800 width and 0-800 height, but the 3d space is different (Way smaller numbers). Or have I missed something? Simply adding that 2d point will take my object out of the screen

Comment: `box_pos` would be the box position in *world coordinates*, possibly mutated by a scale factor. Transforming those to screen coordinates is the job of your MVP matrix.

Comment: sorry man I am trying to understand, so basically let's say my bezier 2d curve has the following points 
Eigen::Vector2f(880.0, 200.0)
Eigen::Vector2f(1100.0, 350.0)
Eigen::Vector2f(1500.0, 450.0)
Eigen::Vector2f(1550.0, 650.0)

Those are the 2d points that you can see in the curve (In the screen)

My actual transformation of the object is :
(0 , 0 , 0) at the beginning (Which is 3d coordinates and not screen ones)

As of right now, I am creating a bezier curve that goes through these 4 points.

Comment: I continue and calculate the points of the curves by inputting a "t" value that grows by a constant and that returns  2d points.
Now I create bezier_3d = vec3(2d point , 0) which will point to (2d screen, 0)

vec3 box_pos now holds => (0,0,0) + (2d point,0) * scale.

Which will be obviously wrong. (Because the (0,0,0)) vector is 3d space.  Should I transfer the bezier_3d to world space? Thanks again, highly appreciated.

Comment: I think the root of your problem is that your bezier curve is in screen coordinates and does not appear to be centered around the origin. You should devise a transformation that scales and translates the screen coordinates back to something that is usable in world coordinates. The better approach is to decouple your bezier transformation from its rendering on screen and just transform it for a) rendering b) application to the 3d world